# Weird entry on my home dir

Tags: linux, rm

I'm on Debian 8, and for some reason, when I do ls on my home dir, the following line appears:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 elade develop5    0 Nov 10 12:28 ?0?@@X?@8?@!???@@@@@?????????@?@?????@@????
```

I can't seem to remove this entry. When I try to rm 'string' I get "no previous search".

Any help or pointing in the right direction is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is it a raspberry?

Comment: No, desktop running Debian 8 with Mate desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to remove that file using:

```
rm -i \?*
```

---

Update:

Does the following list your file?

```
find . -name '*@*@*'
```

And if so, the following should be able to drop it:

```
find . -name '*@*@*' -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Or @jlliagre suggestion looks even better.

Comment: Doesn't work. I'm not sure what is this string, but it is not a directory nor a file, since it doesn't take up any space.

Comment: looks like it is a regular file. An empty one.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to get the inode number of the bogus file with:

```
$ ls -li
...
12345678 -rw-r--r-- 1 elade develop5    0 Nov 10 12:28 ?0?@@X?@8?@!???@@@@@?????????@?@?????@@????
...
```

Then your remove it using that command:

```
find . -inum 12345678 -exec rm -i {} \;
```

Of course, you should replace `12345678` with the actual inode numder.